# How to take inputs for an array using stdin function in same line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```py
N=int(stdin.readline())
Arr=[]
for j in range(N):
    Arr.append(int(stdin))
print(Arr)
```

I got the following error:
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'`

Comment: When you read a line you will get a string. You think have to

Answer (score 2):

To read one line from the console, use the `input()` function. After that use the `split(" ")` to split str to the string array by space delimiter.

```
line = input()
str_arr = line.split(" ")
```

To convert str array to int array. use the bellow code.

```
int_arr = [ int(item) for item in str_arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct way to input list elements in python in a single line:

```
lst = [x for x in input().split()]          // for string input
```

and just use a int(x) inplace of x to convert into integers and store in list